# Why does clicking Chrome on iPhone open a new tab?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome

I got a new iPhone XS a couple weeks ago. Chrome is my default browser. Now, when I click Chrome, it almost always opens a new tab (Google home), whereas it used to always open to the tab that I had previously loaded.

How can I revert to the previous behavior?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, started a few weeks ago and can not figure out why it keeps opening new tabs when I start the chrome app. Have the same issue on both my old and my new iPhone (8 and 12)

Comment: Tried reinstalling it?
And does this happens in safari too?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same answer until I came across your question and did some research, it works for me now. As explained in [this answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/141154470?hl=en&msgid=141165476) on Google Chrome Help Communities, you can reinstall the application completely and then disable sync.

Although disabling sync is a precautionary step, it is not necessary. You can simply reinstall the application and your issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a dumb question - but are you sure you're using Google "Chrome", and not "Google"?

There are two apps:
Google with the "G" logo is the Google AI search app.
Google named "Chrome" with the Color circle icon is the actual Browser.

Google with a "G" will always start you in a search window.

[image: IOS App Screen]

Comment: I wish! That would be a simple solution. Thanks for trying. 

Answer (score 0):

Just had another idea. In the Google Chrome app for iOS, go to the Settings, then Sync and Google Services.

I wonder if maybe the 'sync tabs' is what's doing it. As in, if you close all tabs on the Browser in a PC or Mac, then it may be syncing those closures on the device?

Long shot at this point.

Comment: I tried turning off syncing and still the same problem.

Comment: No I have syncing off and still having the problem.

Comment: I see no option for syncing in iOS Chrome settings.

Answer (score -3):

Settings- click "On startup" then you should have a option to change it  if not then you might be not able to.

Comment: I checked both in iOS Preferences->Chrome and in the settings within Chrome itself and didn't see such an option. Can you add some details and/or a screenshot to make it easier to find?